# Is there any issue in using nsDialogs in experience UI in nsis

Tags: nsis, nsdialogs

As part of solving problem posted here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896705/nsis-getting-error-error-resolving-uninstall-function-un-xpui-skincontrol-in.

I just thought is there any problem in using nsDialogs in experience UI in nsis.

I am strugling like anything while migrating from MUI to experience UI.

Answer (score 0):

can you rule out that nsDialogs is causing this problem, did you try commenting out all nsDialogs-code? just wondering how that error message would indicate such a thing.

Comment: I think problem is not with nsDialogs.Because this error is coming event after commenting out nsDialogs code in my script.

Comment: nsDialog was introduced later than UMUI so it must be based on InstallOptions (.ini files).